# Any shorter syntax for destructuring assignment followed by spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I use the following pattern fairly often while using React:

```
const {foo, bar, pem, das} = this.props;
const props = {foo, bar, pem, das};

return (
   <MyComponent {...props}/>
);
```

I'm just curious if there are any syntactical shortcuts that have escaped me to cut out a step here. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `this.props`?

Comment: I don't want to pass all the props.

Comment: You can write a function that takes an array of names and filters an object.

Comment: @SLaks It's possible I have hundreds of properties within `this.props`, for instance.

Comment: This is also valid: `<MyComponent {...{foo, bar, pem, das}}/>`.

Answer (score 0):

See [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [`Closures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const input = {
  props: {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4, E: 5}
}

// Select specific keys.
const props1 = (({ A, C, D }) => ({ A, C, D }))(input.props)
console.log('Select 1', props1)

// Functional Select.
const select = (obj, ...keys) => keys.reduce((x, k) => ({...x, [k]: obj[k]}), {})
console.log('Select 2', select(input.props, 'A', 'C', 'D'))

// Exclude specific keys.
const { A, C, D, ...props2 } = input.props
console.log('Exclude', props2)
```

Comment: What OP wants is to select specific keys, and your solution is just as WET as what he's doing now, unfortunately - `A, C, D` are being repeated.

Comment: Neat! One less step so +1, though I think I'll stick with what I'm doing currently since it takes fewer keystrokes (less parentheses to line up).

Comment: @ArmanCharan The nice thing about functions is that you only have to write them once, and then you can import and use them anywhere you like without worrying about them again (as long as it has no bugs).

Comment: I agree. Showing people `reduce` over and over just feels a bit hacky ahah  @CertainPerformance Hopefully the `functional` approach suits  @UDrake

Comment: I'm good with functional. I'll try this approach out and see if I like it. Thanks you two. I wish there was a way to do it sans string literals, tho :P.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to select the appropriate properties and add them to an object:

```
function reduceObjectToTheseProps(obj, props) {
  return props.reduce((filteredObjSoFar, prop) => {
    filteredObjSoFar[prop] = obj[prop];
    return filteredObjSoFar;
  }, {});
}

const reducedObj = reduceObjectToTheseProps(myObject, ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need for the temporary variables. Why not destructure in the render params?

```
render = ({ foo, bar, pem, das }) => <MyComponent {...{ foo, bar, pem, das }} />
```